# Почему уходят далеко в сторону буквы при конвертировании canvas в png?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Имеем холст размером 1772px по ширине. Делаем ему «зум» 0.4, и, когда пишем:

```
canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', multiplier: 1});
```

получаем вот это:

[image]

а когда пишем так:

```
canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', multiplier: 1/0.4});
```

получаем такое изображение:

[image]

Как видите, заглавные буквы имен «улетели» далеко влево.

Размер этого шрифта 262px.
Если уменьшить шрифт (например, до 100px), то в обоих случаях будет нормально.

Итого получаем, что можно уменьшить показатель *multiplier* или уменьшить шрифт и только тогда будет нормально отображаться шрифт, иначе это баг какой-то.

Используемый шрифт - `BickhamScriptTwo.ttf`

Как решить эту проблему?

UPD: забыл указать в вопросе, что используется js библиотека fabric.js
UPD: теперь ясно, что не буквы уходят, а они просто перестают отображаться. Вот пример записал https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcWF1RzBeJVbVgzcHpTOFNLTVE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Вы увеличиваете или уменьшаете?

Comment: Я увеличиваю. Но перед этим использовался setZoom(0.4)

Comment: А почему в toDataURL передается какой-то объект? В соотвествии с документацией функция принимает два параметра: формат изображения и его качество.

Comment: Простите, забыл указать что используется js библиотека fabric.js